# Excel VBA- First picture will not load before export

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder with several excel workbooks that I need to export to pdf. There is a logo (.bmp) on each sheet of each workbook. When I use the below code, the pdfs are all missing the logo (it has a grey placeholder instead) on ONLY the first page. The rest of the pages have the logo.

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub dsPdf()
Dim path        As String
Dim wbName      As String

Dim tWb         As Workbook
Dim t           As Single

path = ThisWorkbook.path
wbName = Dir(path & "\*.xlsx")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Do While wbName <> ""
    Set tWb = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & wbName)
    tWb.Sheets(Array(1, 2, 3)).Select
    DoEvents
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        path & "\" & Left(wbName, Len(wbName) - 4) & "pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    tWb.Close False
    wbName = Dir
Loop



End Sub
```

I've tried using `ActiveSheet.RefreshAll` and `DoEvents`, as well as adding a `Timer`/`Do While` loop. When I put `Stop` before the export statement, the first sheet shows the logo correctly. However when I put `Aplication.Wait(Now...` the logo does not show.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: If you step through the macro with `F8`, does it still do that with the first page? Perhaps you can see why, if so, by stepping through? Check the Print Area too, maybe your first page is accidentally starting below your logo?

Comment: If I step through, the logo is shown correctly. Also, when I run the script I can still see the spot where the logo should be, but instead of the logo there's a grey box with (what I assume to be) a "picture not found" symbol. So I believe the print area is correct

Comment: Hm, so I can try on my computer, where exactly is your .bmp in the worksheets? What cell/how large, etc?

Comment: Each cell has a width of 1.86 and a height of 12.75... The logo is in cell B2 and spans to H5 (that comes out to a height of 0.53" and a width of 1.11"). The total print area is from A2 to AN71.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I avoided the use of `.Select`, as (I'm not sure) but I think that could be causing some issues.

```
Sub dsPdf_NoSelect()
Dim path        As String
Dim wbName      As String

Dim tWb         As Workbook
Dim t           As Single
Dim i As Long

path = ThisWorkbook.path
wbName = Dir(path & "\*.xlsx")

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Do While wbName <> ""
        Set tWb = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & wbName)
    For i = 1 To 3
        tWb.Sheets(i).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=path & "\" & Left(wbName, Len(wbName) - 4) & "pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next i
    tWb.Close False
    wbName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This code only outputs the last page (since each time in the for loop it overrides the previous file). However when I added `i` to the file name to make it print all pages to separate pdfs (not ideal, I did this just to see if the first page would come out right) the first page still did not show the logo, where the other pages did.